# selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: 'using' must be a string

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

main.py

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


webpage = r"https://www.instagram.com/"
login = ''

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(webpage)

Weblog = driver.find_element({By.CSS_SELECTOR: {'name': 'username'}})
Weblog.send_keys(login)
```

```
Weblog = driver.find_element({By.CSS_SELECTOR: {'name': 'username'}})
```

I tried all the ways on the Internet, but nothing helped. Help me please

Comment: you have to use it like this: driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "your_CSS_SELECTOR")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should use `(` instead of `{`. Should be something like this:

```
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[name="username"]')
```

Answer (score 0):

**Problem:** Your syntax in code below to locate element using CSS_SELECTOR locator is incorrect.

```
driver.find_element({By.CSS_SELECTOR: {'name': 'username'}})
```

Correct syntax is as below:

```
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name=username]")
```

**Refer the working code below:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

webpage = r"https://www.instagram.com/"
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(webpage)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver,30)

# below line will click on Accept Cookie button
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Allow all cookies']"))).click()
# below line will send username to username textbox
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name=username]"))).send_keys("enter username here")
```

Comment: Gives an error message: AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'element_to_be_clickable'

Comment: Check the updated answer. Add the import statements `By`, `WebDriverWait` and `expected_conditions as EC
`